# How can I protect my ASP.NET API with own Token System

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, authentication

I am trying to protect my asp.net API with a custom System. The problem is that I have no idea how to.

I already have a (simple but working) API running.
The way I want to protect is that in the Authentication Header of the Request should stand a Token. At every connection with my API a method should be called (the method should return a boolean then).

Of course I could easily call that one Method at every HttpRequest -> but that would be too easy xD.

The way I want is to write "[MyCustomAuth]"(example) before ApiController or so......

I hope you understand what I'd like to have.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried searching for "asp.net token authentication" and looked through the articles around the web? This is a fairly common setup, so if you have some more concrete questions please elaborate.

Comment: I think I haven't done something different all day long.....

Comment: Then please elaborate on what's stopping you from implementing some of the solutions you've found? Your question at the moment doesn't really explain what you're having a problem with.

Comment: Ok I try again.... 

In Startup I have the services.AddAuthentication Method -> this method needs the properties of an Authentication Server (doesn't it?) .. but all I want todo is to call a simple method which returns true/false

I don't really want to build an AuthServer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an IAsyncActionFilter for such a scenario (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Example code:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
{    
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        //your custom logic...
        if (//condition where user is not authenticated based on your custom logic)
        {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            return;
        }

        await next();
    }
}
```

and you can use it this way:

```
[CustomAuthorize]
public class YourController: SomeControllerBase
{
}
```